# How to display AM/PM field in Japanese locale using SimpleDateFormat in Java?

Tags: java, datetime, localization, internationalization

I want to display the time in the following format for Japanese "01:00 午後"

My current source code is as follows

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
Date date = cal.getTime();
System.out.println("Start Time "+SimpleDateFormat.getTimeInstance(SimpleDateFormat.MEDIUM,Locale.JAPANESE).format(date));
```

I am getting the following output
Start Time 7:09:37

P.S: I have also tried with setting the time format to "K:mm a" and "H:mm a" . Both of them didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have created object of `SimpleDateFormat` but not using it. Provide `Locale` to this class and see the output.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
Date date = cal.getTime();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy a", Locale.JAPANESE);
System.out.println("Start Time "+ sdf.format(date));
```

Output is : `Start Time 10/16/2015 午後`

Or use `H:mm a` DateFormat instead of `MM/dd/yyyy a` to get the desired out which in case is `Start Time 13:01 午後`

Refer [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) document to know more about the `Date Formats` in Java.

Comment: Thanks, it works!!. I was using the SimpleDateFormat in some other part of the code.